# I am getting same urltoken and sessionid on different system - COLDFUSION 2016

Tags: session, coldfusion, coldfusion-2016

I am facing strange problem. I have an application for calling using twilio. I am using session variables on it. My J2EE session variables is enabled in CF Administrator.

The issue is that when i set any session value then it also got set on browser which is opened onto another system. I have checked that their URLTOKEN is remain same on both browser.

My application.cfc

```
<cfcomponent output="false" hint="I define the application settings and event handlers.">
    <cfset this.name = "applicationName" />
    <cfset this.applicationtimeout=createTimespan(0,6,0,0) />
    <cfset this.sessionManagement="yes" />
    <cfset this.sessionTimeout="#createtimespan(0,1,0,0)#" />
</cfcomponent>
```

Index.cfm with form tag

```
    <cfset SESSION.abc=0>
<form id="formID">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <p><strong>New Client</strong></p>
                            <div class="well well-sm">
                                <span id="successMessage"></span>
                                <input type="text" id="name" class="form-control"    name="name" placeholder="Name">
                            </div>

                            <div class="row" id="connect-agent-row">
                                <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="$('#formID').submit();" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">
                                    Connect
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

Then an ajax is send to an function of cfc. Which set their value by getting from database.

Here is the cfc code.

```
<cfcomponent displayname="abcCFC" hint="abcCFC">
    <cffunction name="setNewSession" returntype="any" returnformat="plain" access="remote">
    <cfargument name="name"  type="string" />
       <cfset var getResults1 = ''>
       <cfquery name="getResults1" datasource="datasourceName">
                    INSERT INTO  tblname(name) VALUES
                    (<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#arguments.name#"  />);
                    Select ident_current('tblname') as ID;
                </cfquery>
                <cfset var SESSION.abc = #getResults1.ID#>
    </cffunction>
</cfcomponent>
```

Here is the ajax code which is working on form submit.

```
$.ajax({
                url: "pathtocfc?method=setNewSession",
                type: "post",
                data: $("form#formID").serialize(),
                success: function(d) {
                    $('#successMessage').html('');
                }
            });
```

I have created a test file and dump the session which is showing correct value after ajax request. Also i am only facing this issue on server has coldfusion 2016.

I have also installed coldfusion2016 on my local and face same problem on firfox but when i set this.setClientCookies="false" on my local. Then this issue got fixed on my local. But this workaround is not work on server.

I need to know that why i am facing this issue and their is any workaround which can solve this problem?

Comment: Are you using `cflocation` in any of your code? If so, by default that will add the session identifiers to the URL. If you don't want that to happen you need override the behavior by setting the `addtoken` attribute to false. Like `<cflocation url = "http://localhost:8500/cfdocs/dochome.htm" addToken = "no">`

Comment: @Miguel-F. No i am not using cflocation anywhere. Let me add some code.

Comment: @Miguel-F. just added some code. :)

Comment: Can you also include your AJAX code?

Comment: @Miguel-F. i have just updated my question with more detail and ajax request code.

Comment: Try deleting the cookies from your machine and see if the problem persists. FWIW you do not need `setClientCookies="true"` for session management to work.

Comment: Not sure I follow. What do you mean by "set on browser which is opened onto another system"?  Also, may be unrelated I do not think you should be using the keyword `var` if you are trying to set a SESSION scoped variable.

Comment: @Leigh. I mean. i opened application on two different systems on same browser(like chrome). If session is set from browser of one system. Then it can be overwrite from another system. It is not generating a different urltoken(combination of cfid,cftoken,jsessionid) and sessionid for different browsers. I will try to change ti to scope_identity() and let you know.

Comment: Just to clarify, "system" meaning two totally different computers/devices?

Comment: @Leigh. Yes. Means two different devices. I also change it to scope_identity(). I still face the same problem

Comment: I am trying to follow along as well. So you open Chrome on one computer and surf to your ColdFusion site. A session is started for computer1. Then on a different computer you open Chrome and surf to your ColdFusion site and get the same session as computer1 ?

Comment: @Miguel-F. Yes.

Comment: Are different browsers doing the same thing?  Internet Explorer,Firefox, etc. or is it limited to Chrome? Are you setting cookies within your code?

Comment: @Miguel-F. yes, other browser are doing the same thing. Also if i setup the same application on my local and test it. Then it is not always causing this issue .

Comment: What about cookies? Also, silly question, but how are you verifying the URLToken, etcetera are the same on each device?

Comment: Are your requests to the ColdFusion server going through a proxy server?

Comment: @Leigh. I am just dumping the session and sees that these values are same. I have also removed cookies. But that not effect.

Comment: @Miguel-F. I am using forwardhq.com to run my application.

Comment: What happened when you deleted cookies from each machine, like Miguel-F suggested?

Comment: My guess would be that the requests being proxied by forwardhq.com are the same as far as the ColdFusion server is concerned so it assigns the same session identifiers. To test this theory, hit your server directly from two different computers and see if you have the same problem.

Comment: @Leigh. Nothing happen. It does not effect on session.

Comment: @Miguel-F. Already hitting 4 different computers.  I just added <cfset StructClear(Session)> before setting session and my testing goes right now. I think, i should give it a try on real server.

Comment: @AbdulRauf - Hm... Miguel-F's theory sounds plausible to me. When you say "nothing happens" - you still had the same problem with multiple computers sharing the same session id's? Did you first a) clear the browser cookies for each machine and b) have each machine hit the CF server *directly* (not through forwardhq.com)?

Comment: @Leigh. The issue is fixed. I used StructClear to clear session and then set the session variable.

Comment: @AbdulRauf - Not sure creating a new session on each request is the best solution. It kind of seems like a "band-aid" fix to a bigger problem. Under normal circumstances, what you described should not happen. Better to figure out *why* it is happening in the first place IMO.

Comment: @Leigh. you are right. I will dig into it and see that why it is happening and will post, if i found any thing.